# NUnit Unit Test with no parameters results Parameter Count mismatch error

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a simple NUnit.Framework.TestCaseAttribute.

In the past, this Unit test used to work but for some reason running this test results in a "Parameter Mismatch error" There is nothing being passed to it and it has no parameters.

The version of NUnit that I am using is 3.12.0.0

```
[TestCase()]
public void TestGroupA_None()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For methods with no args, you can use Test attribute instead of TestCase Attribute

**Sample Code:**

```cs
[Test]
public void TestCaseTest_NoArgs()
{

}
```